# Can I change victory condition mid-game?

Tags: civilization-6

Is there a way to modify a save file (30+ hours of online multiplayer) mid-game to remove/add victory conditions?

E.g. I want to disable diplomatic victory.

Comment: I would assume No since then someone could change them if they were about to lose by that condition

Comment: I see how this can be abused but we are talking about the save file modification which is clearly not intended by developers. In my particular case, we are all friends and agreed upon this.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/civ/comments/1krizp/howto_change_victory_condition_midgame/ there was a way in civ 5, check around in files for something similar in 6

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I spent two evenings to find this and I do not want the information found to disappear.
Did through the creation of new games that differed only in victory conditions. And compared the save files.
I managed to change the victory conditions through the save file through the hex editor (HxD)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6Apx.png

I find sequences for several types of victories

```
1) War          00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0X 00 00 00 5D 0E B5 18 01
2) Diplomacy:   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0X 00 00 00 AD DD 34 E4 05 
3) Culture:     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0X 00 00 00 D1 22 BE EC 01
4) Science:     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0X 00 00 00 8C FF 43 18 01
5) Score:       00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0X 00 00 00 82 4C 6C 62 03
6) Religion:    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0X 00 00 00 D9 DC E5 18 01
```

Replace `0X` to `00`(off) or `01`(on)

---

In the same way, the limit of moves is turned off:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Drua.png

```
on:     00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AF F0 F9 DE E7 A4 0A 2A 02
off:    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 DE 25 99 80 E7 A4 0A 2A 02
```

In total, you need to copy the last save file, open it in the HEX editor and change the flags.