# How do I use a Hex Editor to alter a Civ 6 Save file in order to change Victory Conditions

Tags: civilization-6

I would like to disable the Diplomatic Victory condition in a Civ 6 save file. Looking around, I've found a similar question answered on Arqade, but the answer seems to assume more background knowledge than I have.

Here is the relevant topic:
[Can I change victory condition mid-game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/356803/can-i-change-victory-condition-mid-game)

I have managed to download the hex editor and then using Ctrl+F I found what I think is the right code, by searching for 'AD DD 34 E4 05,' but I'm unsure what to do next.

Here is what I've done

- Changed all the preceding Hexcodes to match those in the top pannel (it reads 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 AD DD 34 E4 05) - no effect
- Changed all the preceding Hexcodes to match those in the top pannel (it reads 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 AD DD 34 E4 05) - no effect
- Attempted to change the hexcode to reflect the sequence listed in the comment (it reads 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0X 00 00 00 AD DD 34 E4 05) - Would not accept 'X'

I have never used a hex editor before and I don't really know what I am doing, but as far as I can tell I've followed the example as closely as possible -- so I must be missing something. I'm looking for a more complete, step-by-step explanation.

Comment: Using a hex editor is fairly not the easiest thing, and as Tahiaji wrote, fiddling for 2 evenings, lets say 8 hours to find the exact part to modify and correctly, is a sound effort. I advise you to not use hex editor, if you don't know what you are doing. I do own the game, and I think I will install to see what method might work. Still, a hint: if your save file does not have originally an X, at that position, don't push it in there. As it is said, it's a flag position, so it will take only 0 or 1 values.